# Show that $f(x)=f(y)$ under certain conditions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f,F:\mathbb R^3\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be two functions such that $f\in C^1$ and the equality
$$\triangledown f(x)=F(x)x^t\hspace{0.7cm}\forall x\in \mathbb R^3$$
holds.

I have to show that in the above case we have $f(x)=f(y)$ for all $x,y\in \mathbb R^3$ with $||x||_2=||y||_2$

Unfortunately I don't have any idea how I should start..

Comment: What is the mark above the x supposed to be at the end of the displayed equation?

Comment: That just means x transposed

Answer (score 0):

If $\|x\| = \|y\|$, then $x$ and $y$ lie on the same sphere about the origin. So you can join them by a smooth curve that lies on this sphere. Now compute $f(x) - f(y)$ using the fundamental theorem of calculus and the given representation of $\nabla f$. Use the fact that the velocity vector of the curve is tangent to the sphere, whereas the gradient of $f$ points radially outwards.

Comment: Okay, so I start with $f(x)-f(y)=\int_{\gamma(0)}^{\gamma(1)}\triangledown f(t)dt$ where $\gamma(0)=y$ and $\gamma(1)=x$?..I guess that something is wrong here since $\triangledown f(t)$ is a vector for every $t$ but it must be a real number for every $t$..

Comment: Check your definition of the line integral

Comment: I know this definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral , but I don't know how I should use it to get $f(x)-f(y)$ on one hand side

Comment: I hoped that I could write something like $f(x)-f(y)=\int_{\gamma}f'(t)dt$, just like for one dimensional functions (functions into $\mathbb R$).